# convert list of tuple into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I'm looking for a way to convert a list of tuples like this:

```
[('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',), ('e',), ('f',), ('h',), ('j',), ('k',), ('l',)]
```

and save it to names.json file like this

```
names : {
  'name':'a',
  'name':'b',
  'name':'c',
  'name':'d',
  'name':'e',
  'name':'f',
  'name':'h',
  'name':'j',
  'name':'k',
  'name':'l'
}
```

Comment: @oskros that code will only keep the last letter as it will always replace whatever is in 'name'. aka it will end up being `{'name': 'l'}`

Comment: This question is unclear. The list of tuples is fine, but the output you describe is not a straight forward dictionary. The syntax `{'a', 'b', 'c', ...}` describes a set, not a dict. So is the output you want a dictionary with a single key "names", and the `set` of all letters from the initial list as its associated value? or do you want a dict with the letters from the initial list as keys? and if so what should the associated value be? to be a dict they must have values, even if that value is `None`.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you wanted something like this:

```
my_list = [('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',), ('e',), ('f',), ('h',), ('j',), ('k',), ('l',)]
my_dict = {x[0]: x[0] for x in my_list}

{'a': 'a',
 'b': 'b',
 'c': 'c',
 'd': 'd',
 'e': 'e',
 'f': 'f',
 'h': 'h',
 'j': 'j',
 'k': 'k',
 'l': 'l'
}
```

**EDIT to updated question:**
What you want here to be is not dictionary but set (indicated by "{}").
I believe that you still want to have dictionary with "names" as key, and **list** as value, like that:

```
my_list = [('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',), ('e',), ('f',), ('h',), ('j',), ('k',), ('l',)]
my_json = {"names": [x[0] for x in my_list]}

{"names": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "h", "j", "k", "l"]}
```

To save it to file you need to do:

```
import json
with open("names.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(my_json, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant have a dictionary like that. Your options are a list of dictionaries:

```
list_of_tuples = [('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',), ('e',), ('f',), ('h',), ('j',), ('k',), ('l',)]

list_of_dicts = [{'name':x[0]} for x in list_of_tuples]

[{'name': 'a'},
 {'name': 'b'},
 {'name': 'c'},
 {'name': 'd'},
 {'name': 'e'},
 {'name': 'f'},
 {'name': 'h'},
 {'name': 'j'},
 {'name': 'k'},
 {'name': 'l'}]
```

or having a unique name for each letter:

```
d = {'name '+str(i):x[0] for i, x in enumerate(list_of_tuples)}

{'name 0': 'a',
 'name 1': 'b',
 'name 2': 'c',
 'name 3': 'd',
 'name 4': 'e',
 'name 5': 'f',
 'name 6': 'h',
 'name 7': 'j',
 'name 8': 'k',
 'name 9': 'l'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each element in a dict is composed by a pair of key and value, and the key must be unique, a dict can only have one element with a specific key, and each time you put a new value to that specific key, the old value will be overwritten, you may want to have a list instead of dict to hold your data.

The example of what would happen if you put multiple value to the same key "name":

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = [('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',), ('e',), ('f',), ('h',), ('j',), ('k',), ('l',)]
    dict = {}
    for tu in t:
        dict["name"] = tu[0]

print(dict)
```

The result is:

```
{'name': 'l'}
```